# C++ access rvalue referenced object from non rvalue object

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

*This question may be sound stupid. I just want to make sure. And maybe that someone point me where this described in standard.*

We cannot have rvalue referenced objects inside lvalue. Right?

```
struct A{int value;};

struct B{
    B(A &&value) : a(std::forward<A>(value)){}
    A&& a;
};

int main()
{
    // allowed
    B(A()).a;

    // error
    B b(A());
    b.a;

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea6bd617d421a8b8

Comment: I'm not sure what what you are actually asking, but `b`is a function an has no `a`.

Comment: @hansmaad Why `b` is a function? I thought it is an object instance of the `B`

Comment: [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B b(A());` declares a function ([most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). You get a compiler error because b has no member a.

To fix the issue write `B b{A()}` instead.

Comment: Yes indeed. So it is allowed to have something like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7612f33c5835fd69 ? I understand that is a dangling reference, and will lead to nowhere. I ask does this allowed by standard? I write rvalue/lvalue cast helper and want to cover all cases.